# Amplify build fails with "Request failed 401 Unauthorized"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-amplify, aws-codeartifact

I am building an amplify react app and trying to connect it to my private npm packages in my CodeArtifact repository.

In the build file `amplify.yml`, I added

```
preBuild:
      commands:
        - aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository myrepo --domain mydomain --namespace mynamespace --domain-owner myid
        - yarn install
```

and gave the amplify service role the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This setup works for CodeBuild building Lambda functions, but in Amplify, I get

`Successfully configured npm to use AWS CodeArtifact repository`

after the login command and

`error An unexpected error occurred: "<some-package-url>: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".`

when installing dependencies.

I debugged the environment in amplify build and did not find any AWS access key id or secret, but also don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolved my issue by deleting `yarn.lock` and adding it to `.gitignore`.

The problem was, that yarn caches the resolved package address in `yarn.lock`. That address was in my CodeArtifact repository, because I was logged in while installing dependencies on my dev machine. Since `yarn.lock` is not in `.gitignore` by default, I just pushed it into the build. When yarn installs dependencies in build, it uses the cached addresses, which can't be reached anymore.

Comment: That's a workaround. It's better to have locked versions of dependencies, so best if `yarn.lock` is not ignored by git.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I agree. But then, what is the correct approach to take here?